# Is it possible to compile Oracle Pro*C without a database (skip semantic check)?

Tags: c++, c, linux, oracle, oracle-pro-c

I am supporting development servers for 35+ versions of the product. Each version may not have same DB schema so traditionally we have to support Oracle instance for each version for the developers to build the Pro*C libraries.

Now the number of versions are too many to support with individual DB instances on individual Linux servers. So I was wondering either of these approaches are possible.

1) To compile Pro*C code (.pc .pcc) without semantic check (I know it's dangerous for release build but for quick test builds, developers don't need to wait for me to provide them a new server)
 2) Have one server with 35+ instances of database, containing only meta data

I searched quite a few places if I can disable semantic check but no success. I tried to configure multiple instances on one Linux server but each instance uses quite a lot memory so having 35+ instances is out of question.

Any clever tricks and suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks,

Tyn

Comment: did u try SQLCHECK=SYNTAX (precompiler).  Also, if you embed PL/SQL blocks in a host program, then you unfortunately must specify SQLCHECK=SEMANTICS.  I admit I haven't done much pro-c in a long while, so I'd be interested if this works

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But there are thousands (if not millions) of lines of legacy code in my product so I would prefer to change  in make files' compiler setting to disable semantic check rather than excluding via pre-compiler in individual pc/pcc code.

Comment: I believe you can put precompiler options in one config file

Comment: Hi @tbone. I finally got round to trying your suggestion and see what you mean. Unfortunately my legacy Pro*C code has so many PL/SQL calls so I still have to turn on SEMANTICS check. Looks like I'll end up with 2nd plan of having many db instances on one server. What I'm thinking is not keeping those DB instances mounted all the time so all 35+ (meta data only) db instances can live on one server. Thanks for your suggestion anyway. Should have check the Pro*C documentation first. Cheers.

Comment: Pro*C compiles against a schema.   I would think that 35 schemas in one or more instance would be viable.  Do you actually have 35 versions of the program in production?